# Where is the element of time in the definition of work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, time, work

In $\text{Work} = m \times a \times \text{distance}$.

From this equation, How can we know the duration of the force that have been applied
in order to move the object over that distance?

Comment: If I buy 3 pizzas for 8 dollars each, I pay 24 dollars. More general, the price you pay for n pizzas is n_pizza * 8_dollars = total_prize. Where is the element of time here? E.g. how long do I need to work to have the money for one pizza? It does not appear at all! Time does not have to be a part of every equation ;) Some relations answer just different questions, independent of time. And, as here, leave it free to other factors (e.g. you can earn a lot/month or a few/month, in both cases you can buy the pizzas... it is independent/another question)

Comment: @Mayou36 That is not an equivalent analogy, because there really isn't a time factor there, but acceleration does have it.

Comment: Acceleration does not have a time factor either. It just has time in it's unit. But I understand your confusion. Think of the pizza example again and add a "per month" to every unit. Like: 3 pizzas *per month*,  24 dollars *per months*, how much do I need to work *per month*... and all the relations stay the same. Or basically, I have multiplied both sides of the equation with the same magnitude (or rather, divided).  But, the "per month" has *nothing to do* with how long I have to work, although it's time as well. Same goes for the $t^{-2}$ in the acceleration.

Comment: Whether an Acceleration is constant or variable, it still describes a change over time, and that's what i am missing here, because force has acceleration as a factor.

Comment: So following your argumentation, energy also describes a change over time, right? Because energy has the $t^{-2}$ in it as well. See, it's getting tricky here. The simple answer is the one given above. Read it through again, you will see that just because time occurs in the unit does not mean there is a direct interpretation of how much time is needed for... The other thing is a more general question about units. And this requires some more in-depth understanding with Noethers theorem or, the simple observation, that energy just *is* conserved. And has time in it's unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest case of a straight line movement with a constant force starting from a zero speed, from energy conservation

$$W=\dfrac{mv^2}{2}=\dfrac{m(2v_a)^2}{2}=2m\left(\dfrac{d}{t}\right)^2$$

Where $v_a$ is the average speed. The solution for time follows

$$t=\sqrt{\dfrac{2m}{W}}\cdot d$$

Comment: Why did you write that W equals the Kinetic Energy equation ?

Comment: Yes, according to the energy conservation law, all work in this case goes to increase the kinetic energy.

Answer (score 12):

First of all: in general you cannot substitute $F_r=ma$ into $W=Fd$, the reason being that the work equation can be applied for any force, while Newton's 2nd law refers to the resultant force $F_r$. Also, if the force $F$ isn't constant, and we are in 3D, then work is calculated as $W=\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x}$.

As for where's time in $W=Fd$, there's the time it takes for the distance $d$ to be covered, but, yes, time isn't really playing a role in this equation and, in general:

- you cannot know the duration of the interaction from the work of the force alone.

Time does appear in the related concept of power (time rate of work: $P_\text{avg}=W/\Delta t$). So you can calculate $\Delta t$, given total $W$ and $P_\text{avg}$.

Comment: I see, but how can work be calculated if we don't know the duration of the force? isn't that a false value ?

Comment: No, it's not false, it's consistent with the rest of the theory, e.g., with the [Energy-work relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work.E2.80.93energy_principle). Once you've gone trough at least the very basic of mechanics, things should become clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Work is defined as $W=\int \vec F\cdot d\vec \ell$.  It may be that the force is  time-dependent so let's write $\vec F=\vec F(t)$.  You can then introduce time explicitly by writing 
$$
d\vec \ell =\frac{d\vec \ell}{dt}dt = \vec v(t) dt\, .
$$
In this case you simply end up with 
$$
W=\int \vec F(t)\cdot \vec v(t) dt\, .\tag{1}
$$
This last expression can be useful in some cases to show that a force does no work when it is perpendicular to $\vec v(t)$.  Thus the magnetic force $\vec F_{mag}= q\vec v\times \vec B$ is automatically perpendicular to $\vec v$ by the properties of the cross product, and can be seen to do no work as
$$
\left(q\vec v\times \vec B\right)\cdot \vec v \equiv 0\, .
$$

Comment: I am a little confused, isn't a force always time dependent ?

Comment: @physicsnewbie how about the force of gravity near the Earth: constant and equal in magnitude to $g$.

Comment: But when we are not moving or falling, wouldn't that mean there is no work  done on our bodies from the force of gravity?

Comment: @physicsnewbie sorry first that would be $mg$, not $g$.  If you are not moving $\vec v=0$ then there is no displacement so no work is done.

Comment: And when a person is falling and crossing a distance d, don't we need to know how much time they were being pulled by the force of gravity in order to calculate work ?

Comment: No we don’t.  In this case the force is constant and the work done is just $mg\times d$, where $d$ is the *vertical* distance travelled.

Comment: @physicsnewbie If work is being done on you when you are not falling *where does that work come from and where does it go*?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, but if something was slowing it down it would move a shorter distance with the same force.

Comment: @tfb According to the definition of work, when i am not moving, no work is done.

Comment: @physicsnewbie Exactly so.

Comment: @physicsnewbie it is we’re slowing down there would be a force acting on it.

Comment: I'm familiar with all the mathematical notation  and abbreviations in this post except for `dl`. Could you spell it out, since it seems to be crucial to your answer that work depends on it instead of time?

Comment: @Noumenon $d\vec \ell$ is a directed line element, tangent at one point along the path to the path connecting the initial and final position vectors which are the bounds in the integral defining the work.  It is sometimes denoted $d\vec x$ or (as in this wiki page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_element) $d\vec s$.